# How to check if a value is between any 2 values in a range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to check if a value from column E is between any pair of values in A:B and if so, return a letter from column C. Desired result is in F column.

[image: example]

Comment: for those inputs what would be your expected outputs?  As I see it 3 could have many answers.

Comment: `VLOOKUP()`? What have you tried? What's the expected result?

Comment: @ScottCraner let's say it's 15 instead of 3, so that it cannot appear in two pairs

Comment: Umm...15 would not return anything.  Currently `1` has one match.  `3` ahs three, and `5` has four matches.  Do you want them all in one cell, the first found, the last found,....?  What should the output be and what should it look like.

Comment: The output should just be the letter from C column. And let's assume that only one or zero matches are possible.

Comment: Then fix your data to show that, Your new data still shows four possible answers for 5 and 0 for 15.  Your words and your data do not match, so we do not know how to answer.

Comment: Fixed the screenshot

Comment: What if a value is within more than one range? e.g `6` is within all `a`,`c`,`d`, and `e`

Comment: @SardarUsama I want to check if 1 is in any range of what is in A:B, so 1-10, 2-5, 6-9, 2-8 or 4-7. Same thing for 15 and 10. These are just sample data to make it simple.

Comment: Let's assume that only one or zero matches are possible

Comment: Then please create an example that represents your actual data. Your current example doesn't

Comment: @JNevill lookup function gives an approximate match and searches a given column, not row

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry I missed that you have values that won't be in any range.

Answer (score 0):

I think an Array formula using `Match()` to get the row on which the hit is found that is then passed to `INDEX()` may solve this:

```
 =INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(E3>=A:A)*(E3<=B:B),0))
```

That's an Array formula (CSE Formula) so you'll have to Ctrl+Shift+Enter it so it gets the squirrelly brackets.

If you have a value that falls into more than one range, this will return the first row too, which is a nice feature.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot ;)